# List all files added/modified on date

Tags: unix, find

How can I use the find command to list all files for example modified on april 9 2011.

Thank you,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good suggestions here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date

and

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-files-by-date/

I personally would use the `-mtime` option, but depending on your version of Linux/find, you may be able to use the options listed in the first link...

Answer (score 0):

You want the `-mtime` option to find. You'll need to calculate how long ago the day you want is.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use 'ls' from the parent directory of the possible directories the files I want are held

```
ls -alhR | grep "Feb 22"
```

where "Feb 22" is the date you're looking for. This is a terrible method due to it showing any files editing on Feb 22, regardless of the year - but usually this isn't an issue for me. If you need on or after X date, go with the other suggestions of using mtime.